# Указать позиции с которых начинаются самое короткое и самое длинное слово

Tags: c#, строки, linq

Входные данные:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Выходные:

> Самое короткое 61, самое длинное 257

Однако из-за особенностей работы IndexOf правильный ответ я получить не смог.

Мой код:

```
var words = str.Split(' ').OrderBy(x => x.Length);
Console.WriteLine($"Индекс самого длинного слова: {str.IndexOf(words.Last())}\nИндекс самого короткого слова: {str.IndexOf(words.First())}");
```

Comment: У вас занятые, точки, тире, кавычки и пр тоже являются частью слова?

Comment: Ошибка в том, что самое короткое слово может быть подстрокой более длинного слова. Правильно - добавить разделитель (пробел) к началу и концу как исходного текста, так и искомого слова, после чего использовать IndexOf. Также Вы получите неверный ответ, если в тексте есть два разделителя (пробела) подряд.

Comment: @tym32167 Да, их я не игнорировал.

Comment: @Akina про два пробела, вот [предыдущий вопрос автора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1003093/179763)

Comment: Что делать если несколько самых коротких/длинных слов? Важно ли что нужно вывести позицию «do», а не «ut»?

Comment: @default locale нужно именно первое, т.е. «do».

Comment: @Akina Добавил в конце искомых слов добавил пробел и получил правильный ответ, спасибо

Comment: @Gendalf, всё равно неправильно.

Comment: @Qwertiy♦ Не будет находить нужное слово в конце строки?

Comment: @Gendalf, и это тоже. И ещё вот так: `sudo do done`.

Comment: *Добавил в конце искомых слов добавил пробел и получил правильный ответ* Добавьте в конец текста слово из одной буквы. Или добавьте в начало слова, последние 2 символа коих 'do'. Сказано же было - **И** в начале, **И** в конце, **И** тексту, **И** слову.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще стоило бы руками написать цикл, но сойдёт и вот так при помощи linq: https://ideone.com/rSSluo

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    var s = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";
    var lens = Regex.Matches(s, @"\w+").Cast<Match>().ToList();

    var minLen = lens.Min(m => m.Value.Length);
    var maxLen = lens.Max(m => m.Value.Length);

    var minStart = lens.First(m => m.Value.Length == minLen).Index;
    var maxStart = lens.First(m => m.Value.Length == maxLen).Index;

    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", minStart, maxStart);
  }
}
```

Comment: Можно было отсортировать Match'и по Value.Length, и потом взять First и Last, https://ideone.com/XFphHq

Comment: @PrimusSingularis 1. Не надо асимптотику портить сортировкой. 2. А с чего ты взял, что OrderBy делает устойчивую сортировку? Вроде он такого не заявляет. А вообще, тут даже устойчивая не поможет. Это вообще неверно будет.